# env-vars in React using Dotenv and Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dotenv

I want to access some of my environment variables defined in the frontend (React).

I have the following setup:

- React + NodeJS (I do NOT use `create-react-app`)
- Webpack 4
- Dotenv

I have tried to follow https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5#0618 but it does not work either any error is thrown.

`webpack.config.js`

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

module.exports = () => {
  // call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

  // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    console.log(prev)
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});

return { 
  ...,
  plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
  ],
  ...
}
```

With above Webpack config I think I should be able to do `<h4>My var: {process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VAR}</h4>` in `file.js`, of course I have defined `REACT_APP_MY_VAR` in my `.env`-file located in the project root.

With above I expect `file.js` to render the value of `REACT_APP_MY_VAR`, but i does render nothing, either the value or an error.

Comment: `dotenv` is meant to keep secrets out of your code as it moves from developer machine to CI environments to production servers. If some untrusted person gets your code, they don't also get your secrets. Frontend code is different. You're _always_ sending it to browsers to be read by anyone. Don't put sensitive information in frontend code and skip using dotenv to avoid a false sense of security. Instead, you can define an object for `webpack.DefinePlugin` directly (what `envKeys` becomes)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `dotenv-webpack` instead of `dotenv` package for easy configuration.

**4 simple steps:-**

1) install `dotenv-wepack` using

`npm install dotenv-webpack --save`

2) Create `.env` file at root of application

`API_URL=http://localhost:8000`

3) Add this to your webpack config file.

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

4) Use env variable inside your application anywhere.

```
import React from 'react';

    const App = () => {
        return (
            <h1>{process.env.API_URL}</h1>        
        );
    }
    export default App;
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks! It works but I prefer to use dotenv as that way I can make sure no secrets are exposed (I will check that env-var name starts with "REACT_APP_") and I have not found a way to do that with `dotenv-webpack`...